# Office 2010 KMS question

Tags: activation, kms, licensing

I have deployed a KMS server in our environment which does different versions of Windows but also Office 2010.  Regarding office 2010 and its expiration, what is the max time?

For Windows clients it can go up to 180 days without talking to the KMS host before it becomes unlicensed, but it seems Office will become unlicensed after 7 days.  Is this correct?  I saw this by displaying the license information (slmgr -dli).  So Office uses different times then Windows?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... mostly a reading error.  I also realized that the licensing script is different then slmgr.  Solved.

Comment: Looking back through some old posts.  I should have mentioned the KMS licensing information for Office is the ospp.vbs script.  There is a great post here http://blogs.technet.com/b/office2010/archive/2009/12/18/volume-activation-tips-and-tricks.aspx

Answer (score 1):

According to the Office 2010 Resource Kit documentation ([link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff603508.aspx)) it is supposed to be 180 days as well:

> All KMS clients must connect to the KMS host at least one time every 180 days to reactivate.

Answer (score 0):

Initial activation is sooner than 180 days but 7 days seems a little short, I recall having 30 days (it might have been longer) before I started seeing warning messages (we never had the 5 required clients to KMS activate so switched to MAK licensing)